# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Team must exist

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Team must exist` when I run `rake db:seed`.

I am trying to set an association between Players and Teams. I have data I want to seed into my database, but I am unsure if the error is being caused with how I have set up my association or how I have structured my data.

Team being the parent and Player being the child.

Models

```
# player.rb
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, class_name: "Player"

  validates :team, presence: true, allow_nil: true
end


# team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end
```

Routes

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :players

  resources :teams do
    resources :players
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Migrations

```
# create_players.rb
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.belongs_to :team, index: true

      t.string :name

      t.string :shoots
      t.string :catches
      t.string :position
      t.string :pos
      t.integer :number
      t.integer :gp
      t.integer :goals
      t.integer :assists
      t.integer :points
      t.integer :pim
      t.integer :plusMinus
      t.decimal :gaa
      t.integer :svs

      t.integer :team_id
      t.references :teams

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


# create_teams.rb
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|

      t.string :team_name
      t.string :abr
      t.string :sm_logo
      t.string :lg_logo

      t.integer :player_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Data example of data attempting to seed

```
# Player data
players = Player.create!({
  "name": "Some Guy",
  "shoots": "Right",
  "position": "Forward",
  "pos": "F",
  "number": 8,
  "gp": 15,
  "goals": 12,
  "assists": 6,
  "points": 18,
  "pim": 12,
  "plusMinus": 7,
  "team_id": 1
})


# Team data
teams = Team.create!({
  "team_name": "A Team",
  "abr": "ATM"
})
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

#Bootstrap 4 and Tether gems
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create the team:

```
team = Team.create!({ team_name: "A Team", abr: "ATM" })
```

Notice that I pass a `hash` to the `create!` method, not an `array` with a hash, like you had in your example.

Then you can create the player and add them to the team:

```
player = Player.create!({
  "name": "Some Guy",
  "shoots": "Right",
  "position": "Forward",
  "pos": "F",
  "number": 8,
  "gp": 15,
  "goals": 12,
  "assists": 6,
  "points": 18,
  "pim": 12,
  "plusMinus": 7,
  "team": team
})
```

Notice that I am able to pass the `team` object to the  `Player.create!` method. This will associate the player with the team. Otherwise you can just use the id.

```
player = Player.create!({
  ...
  team_id: team.id
})
```

OR

```
player = Player.create!({
  ...
  team_id: 1
})
```

The ellipsis (3 dots) should be replaced by the actual attributes as shown above.

**Update**

Remove the following lines from the `create_players.rb` migration:

```
  t.integer :teams_id
  t.references :teams
```

Remove the following line from the `create_teams.rb` migration:

```
  t.integer :player__id
```

Writing `t.belongs_to :player` produces the same results as writing `t.integer :player_id`. It's just Rails syntactic sugar. Writing `t.belongs_to :player` or `t.references :player` is just a little more clear than writing `t.integer :player_id`

I'm assuming that you want one player to belong to one team (a one-to-many relationship). If you think that a player could belong to multiple teams (not usually the case, but I don't know what you're developing) than you would need to do a Google search for a Rails many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Answer, this has moved the issue along but I am now getting error:
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0..1)`

This is after updating the Player data to seed to:
`player = Player.create!({
  ...
  team_id: 1
})`

and updating the player migration to `t.integer :team_id` from being `teams_id` plural.

I've searched for answers on the new error but again I'm getting no where.

Comment: the ellipsis (3 dots) was just a placeholder for all the other attributes. I hope you didn't literally type `player = Player.create!({ ... team_id: 1 })` in your editor

Comment: I also noticed you have `t.integer :player__id` in your `create_teams.rb` migration. It should have one underscore, not 2. I hope that's just a typo on Stack Overflow. Second of all, you don't need that line in this migration. Also, you should remove `t.belongs_to :player, index: true` from the same migration. The `player` should belong to a `team` but you don't need to add a column on the `teams` table for players. It's a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: hahaha @Greg Answer yes I realise that the `...` is for brevity so no, I did not place it in literally :)

I have edited my code and question with your new suggested changes but again I am getting the same error `wrong number of arguments ...` error

Comment: I also updated my answer. Please make sure you are passing a hash like this `player = Player.create!({ ... team_id: 1 })` and not a hash wrapped in an array like this `player = Player.create!([{ ... team_id: 1 }])`. Notice the square brackets `[ { ... } ]`? Remove them. It should only be a hash like this `{ ... }`

Comment: yes sorry was entering the seed data as `create!( { ... team_id: 1 } )` have now updated that in the question only. 

have updated as per your edited answer and still getting `wrong number of arguments error`

Comment: In a terminal window, enter `rails console`. When it loads, make sure you have at least one team in the database by entering `Team.create!({ team_name: "A Team", abr: "ATM" })`. enter `Player.create!()`, see what the output is. Try entering `Player.create!(team_id: 1)` (without any other attributes). And also try `Player.create()` without the exclamation mark. Did you add any other attributes or gems to the `Player` model? Did you change the `self.create!` method? Otherwise, you might want to post another question with the new error and all the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks @greg Answer, I ran all examples, they give an error saying `Validation failed: Team must exist`.

When I run `Player.create()` it works, a player is added with no error but it does not create the `Player` with a `player_id`. I'm new to this so this might be how it is supposed to work. I simply do not know.

In terms of your other questions, I have added no attributes to the `Player` model and have not changed the `self.create!` method. Only a few gems have been added and I have posted the `gemfile` in my original question now as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Greg Answer thank you for your help. I have now found a working solution.

To fix I reverted back to a previous commit and decided to follow the following article:
https://www.learneroo.com/modules/137/nodes/767

My finished working code looks as follows:

Models

```
# Team model
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end

# Player model
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Migrations

```
# create_teams.rb
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|

      t.string :team_name
      t.string :abr

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# create_players.rb
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :shoots
      t.string :catches
      t.string :position
      t.string :posAbr
      t.string :abr
      t.integer :number
      t.integer :gp
      t.integer :goals
      t.integer :assists
      t.integer :points
      t.integer :pim
      t.integer :plusMinus
      t.decimal :gaa
      t.integer :svs

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# add_team_id_to_players.rb
class AddTeamIdToPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :players, :team_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Seed data examples

```
# Team data
teams = Team.create([{
  "team_name": "A Team",
  "abr": "ATM"
}])

# Player data
players = Player.create!([{
  "name": "Some Guy",
  "shoots": "Right",
  "position": "Forward",
  "pos": "F",
  "number": 8,
  "gp": 15,
  "goals": 12,
  "assists": 6,
  "points": 18,
  "pim": 12,
  "plusMinus": 7,
  "team_id": 1
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your association in the `class Player` is wrong, see when you must use:

If the name of the other model cannot be derived from the association name, you can use the :class_name option to supply the model name. For example, if a book belongs to an author, but the actual name of the model containing authors is Patron, you'd set things up this way:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "Patron"
end
```

See all options to use this association: [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to)